# Enable a Cargo feature by default when the target arch is WASM?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, wasm-bindgen

Part of my Cargo.toml for my crate:

```
[features]
wasm = ["ed25519-dalek/nightly", "rand/wasm-bindgen", "js-sys"]
```

This works, when the crate is used in another project, and the "wasm" feature is explicitly chosen.

I want to automatically enable this feature only when the target arch is WASM. I tried adding this:

```
#[cfg(target_arch = "wasm32")]
default = ["wasm"]
```

When I compile for a target other than WASM, "wasm" is included as the default, how can I make "wasm" the default only when the target is WASM?

Comment: Have you defined your default set of features (`default` under `[features]`)? If not, `wasm` might be getting pulled in automatically.

Comment: Actually, it is certainly getting pulled in. `default-features = off` or set a `default` set of features to avoid this.

Comment: If I add default = [] before the cfg line, the toml won't parse due to a duplicate key. Is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: Let me just write an answer, comments are terrible for this. You can let me know if it works :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only have target-specific dependencies, not target-specific features. This is a [known bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1197) that is unfortunately opened since 2015.

People expects this syntax to be supported, but right now there is nothing scheduled to make this work:

```
[target.'cfg(target_arch = "wasm32")'.features]
default = ["ed25519-dalek/nightly", "rand/wasm-bindgen", "js-sys"]
```

As a ugly workaround, you can create another crate [that depends on your crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#platform-specific-dependencies) and let the user use this new crate:

```
[target.'cfg(target_arch = "wasm32")'.dependencies.your_crate]
version = "1.0.0"
features = ["wasm"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I ended up using `build.rs` to enable features when a specific target is used.

```ini
[target.'cfg(all(target_arch = "wasm32", target_os = "unknown"))'.dependencies]
web-sys = { version = "0.3.64", features = ["Storage", "Window", "console"] }

[features]
sqlite = ["dep:rusqlite", "dbson/rusqlite"]
gui = []
default = ["gui"]

wasm = []
```

`build.rs`

```rust
pub fn main() {
    if std::env::var("TARGET").expect("Unable to get TARGET").contains("wasm32") {
        println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=feature=\"wasm\"");
    }
}
```

Here I wanted to enable `wasm` feature when the target is wasm32-unknown-unknown.

Note that this is not supported by cargo and this is run after dependency resolution.

So If I made `web-sys` optional and used `wasm = ["dep:web-sys"]` as a feature that wouldn't work.

Comment: It is probably better to have a `cfg` instead of a feature so the user cannot turn it on by mistake on non-WASM platforms.